# In JavaScript, how can serializer part of the DOM to XHTML?

Tags: javascript, dom, xhtml, innerhtml, xmlserializer

I would like to serialize part of the DOM to XHTML (valid XML). Let's assume I have just one element inside `<body>`, and that this is the element I want to serialize:

```
<div>
    <hr>
    <img src="/foo.png">
</div>
```

With this, `document.innerHTML` gives me almost what I want, except it returns HTML, not XHTML (i.e. the `<hr>` and `<img>` won't be properly closed). Since `innerHTML` doesn't do the trick, how can I serialize part of the DOM to XHTML?

Comment: What browser compatibility are you after? [This works in Firefox and Chrome for me](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLSerializer). I don't know about IE though. I found something were they use a wrapper like `if( !window.XMLSerializer ){ window.XMLSerializer = function(){}; window.XMLSerializer.prototype.serializeToString = function( XMLObject ){ return XMLObject.xml || ''; };}`, although I don't know for which browser it is (Mac -> no IE to test).

Comment: **Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qUwXE/ (but it doesn't work in Chrome and Safari)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Thanks... actually I used it on a parsed XML document, where it also worked in Chrome. Too bad it does not work with the HTML.

Comment: Ideally I'd like this to work on IE6+, and recent version of Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and Safari. Now, to get started, something that works on both Chrome and Firefox will do. Unfortunately, on Chrome, the XMLSerializer outputs HTML when the input is HTML DOM, as noted in this bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=36349. One of the comment suggests a workaround, which I'll be trying out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if using another language (on top of the JavaScript engine) is an option. If this is of any help, this would be the XQuery (XQIB) way of doing it:

```
<script type="application/xquery">
  serialize(b:dom()//div)
</script>
```

For example, in the following page, the serialized XHTML is written as text on the page instead of the script tag, after the div tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>   
    <title>Serializing part of the DOM</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mxqueryjs/mxqueryjs.nocache.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <hr>
      <img src="/foo.png">
    </div>
    <script type="application/xquery">
      serialize(b:dom()//div)
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The HTML DOM is mapped to the XQuery data model (a data model on top of XML). b:dom() returns the document node of the page, and //div navigates to all descendant div tags. The serialize function then serializes this to a string.

However, this will work for IE9+ (not 6+) and recent versions of Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera.

Answer (score 0):

this is not tested code, but I would scan recursively children of the parent element and build XHTML like this:

```
var parent;
var parse = function(el) {
  var res = "";
  for(var i=0; i < el.childNodes.length; i++) {
    var child = el.childNodes[i];
    res += "<"+child.tagName;
    // scan through attributes
    for(var k=0; k < child.attributes.length; k++) {
      var attr = child.attributes[k];
      res += " "+attr.name+"='"+attr.value+"'";
    }
    res += ">";
    res += parse(child);
    res += "</"+child.tagName+">";
  }
  return res;
}
var xhtml = parse(parent);
```

Comment: Maybe manually serializing is the only cross-browser compliant way, but is is a bit more complicated. Your code as it is does not work. There should be a library for this somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

[Sarissa](http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa), the cross-browser Javascript compatibility library has an XMLSerializer implementation for browsers that lack one:

http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/jsdoc/symbols/XMLSerializer.htm

[They also have an example of how to use it](http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/howtos.html#serializedom), which is just:

```
var xmlString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(someXmlDomNode);
```

According to them, the browser support for their library is good:

> Supported browsers are Mozilla - Firefox and family, Internet Explorer with MSXML3.0 and up, Konqueror (KDE 3.3+ for sure), Safari and Opera.